# how can i traverse multiple screen javafx?

Tags: java, javafx

really, I need to know how can I go from Login screen to mainMenu screen in javafx

```
public class LoginUIController implements Initializable {


    @FXML
    PasswordField pasf = new PasswordField();

    @FXML
    Button bt1 = new Button();
    @FXML
    Button bt2 = new Button();
    @FXML
    Button bt3 = new Button();
    @FXML
    Button bt4 = new Button();
    @FXML
    Button bt5 = new Button();
    @FXML
    Button bt6 = new Button();
    @FXML
    Button bt7 = new Button();
    @FXML
    Button bt8 = new Button();
    @FXML
    Button bt9 = new Button();
    @FXML
    Button bt0 = new Button();
    @FXML
    Button btLogin = new Button();
    @FXML
    Button btDelete = new Button();
    @FXML
    Button btClose = new Button();
    @FXML
    Label timeLb = new Label();



    @Override
    public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources) {

        pasf.setEditable(false);
        setActions();
        setFocus();

    }


    private void setActions(){

        bt0.setOnMouseClicked(e->{pasf.appendText("0");});
        bt1.setOnMouseClicked(e->{pasf.appendText("1");});
        bt2.setOnMouseClicked(e->{pasf.appendText("2");});
        bt3.setOnMouseClicked(e->{pasf.appendText("3");});
        bt4.setOnMouseClicked(e->{pasf.appendText("4");});
        bt5.setOnMouseClicked(e->{pasf.appendText("5");});
        bt6.setOnMouseClicked(e->{pasf.appendText("6");});
        bt7.setOnMouseClicked(e->{pasf.appendText("7");});
        bt8.setOnMouseClicked(e->{pasf.appendText("8");});
        bt9.setOnMouseClicked(e->{pasf.appendText("9");});
        btDelete.setOnMouseClicked(e->{pasf.clear();});
        btClose.setOnMouseClicked(e->{

        Stage stage = (Stage) btClose.getScene().getWindow();
        stage.close();

        });   
        btLogin.setOnMouseClicked((MouseEvent e)->{

        }); 
    }

    private void setFocus(){

        pasf.requestFocus();
        bt0.requestFocus();
        bt1.requestFocus();
        bt2.requestFocus();
        bt3.requestFocus();
        bt4.requestFocus();
        bt5.requestFocus();
        bt6.requestFocus();
        bt7.requestFocus();
        bt8.requestFocus();
        bt9.requestFocus();
        btClose.requestFocus();
        btDelete.requestFocus();
        btLogin.requestFocus();
    }  
}
```

---

```
public class MainMenuController  implements Initializable {

    @Override
    public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources) {


    }

}
```

---

```
public class MyApp extends Application {

    public final static String LOGIN_FXML = "/myapp/LoginUI.fxml";
    public final static String MAINMENU_FXML = "/myapp/MainMenu.fxml";

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws IOException {





        primaryStage.setTitle("Hello World!");
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

}
```

Comment: Have you tried simply putting the login and main menu screens in separate stages and then simply switching between the two stages when the login attempt succeedes? Anyway, just google javafx stage/scene switching and you will get tons of info.

Comment: Option 1 is what i trying to do , can you edit my project to do it :                     the link to project:  https://goo.gl/EaktzQ   and send it to mostafabayomui@yahoo.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you have two options:

1. Create two Stages one for the Login and one for the Main part. When your login is successful hide the Login Stage and show the Main Stage.
2. Create one Stage with the Login Content in it and the Main Content in it. When login succeeds hide the Login content and show the main Content.

Comment: Option 1 is what i trying to do , can you edit my project to do it :                     the link to project:  https://goo.gl/EaktzQ   and send it to mostafabayomui@yahoo.com

Comment: I'm not here to do your work :P. But I'll take a look at it.

Comment: Seeing your Code I think you realy are a Beginner with JavaFX. I would recommend to read some Tutorials about JavaFX and FXML stuff. 
http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/get_started/fxml_tutorial.htm 
https://www.google.de/search?q=javafx+tutorial

Comment: Thank you very much for the extra help you gave me.